# Notation clarification (ex. $\int P(x,dy)$)

Tags: probability-theory, lebesgue-measure

I have two cases I would like an explaination for the notation

1. $f(dy)=\int F(x,dy)dx$
2. $h(x)=\int P(x,dy)$

I do not know what they are supposed to mean. if $f$ in 1. a measure meaning $f(dy)=f(y)dy$? How about 2.? How am I to understand these?

And the last one from the text I am reading

3. $Q^n(x,S)=\int Q^n(x,dz)=\int \int Q(x,dy)Q^{n-1}(x,dz)$

On the example of 3. is the following correct

$Q^n(x,S)$ states the measure of the $Q^n(x,y)$ over the set $S$, which is measured than by $\int Q^n(x,dz)$, which is the same as $\int Q^n(x,z)dz$? But how do we pass to the second equality? Is it 
$$\int \int Q(x,dy)Q^{n-1}(x,dz)=\int \int Q(x,y)dyQ^{n-1}(x,z)dz=\int Q(x,S)Q^{n-1}(x,dz)$$$$=Q(x,S)\int Q^{n-1}(x,dz)=Q(x,S)Q^{n-1}(x,S)=Q^{n}(x,S)$$

I thank you in advance

#### Edit in regards to comments

[image]
[image]

[image]
And put differently (same result, same theorem.
[image]

#### Edit 2

Yet in another paper (Understanding MH algorithm) it says

[image]

I feel drowned in all this different notation. Perhaps an explanation of what is meant by $\pi$ is the density with respect to the measure $\pi^*$. Does this mean $$d\pi^*(y)=pi^*(dy)=\pi(y)dy?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are  multivariable extensions of  notations like $A=\int f(x)\mu(dx)$ for what might otherwise be written as $B=\int f(x) d\mu=\int fd\mu$ or $C=\int f(x) d\mu(x)$ or $D=\int f(x) \frac{d\mu}{dx} \,dx=\int f(x) m(x) dx$, where $m$ is the Radon Nikodym derivative of $\mu$ (so that for all measurable $A$ we have $\mu(A)=\int_A m(x)dx$).

(There are other notations for integrating the function $f$ with respect to the measure $\mu$, such as $\langle\mu,f\rangle$ and $\mu(f)$, but they are not germane to this discussion.)

The notation $A$ makes clear the variable being integrated over, more clearly I think than  notation $B$.
Notation $C$ is misleading, in the sense that measures are functions of sets and not numbers, so $\mu(x)$ is born mysterious.  (I think I've seen the pedantically correct variant $\int f(x)d\mu(-\infty,x])$ or $\int f(x)dM(x)$ where $M$ is the cdf of $\mu$.) Notation $D$ makes sense [that is, is correct] only for those measures $\mu$ that are absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure, that is have densities, but is probably most comfortable to students who have taken calculus classes but are not comfortable with measure theory.

So in your case $F$ is the name for a collection of measures on $Y$ space,  specifying, for each value of $x$, the measure $A\mapsto F(x,A)$ on $Y$. A nickname for this measure is $F(x,dy)$, where the $dy$ indicates that $y$ is the variable of integration when you use this measure.  When you integrate $h(y)$ against this measure, you get $g(x) = \int h(y) F(x,dy)$  The $dy$ tells you that that's the variable of integration, and $x$ is the free variable: this defines a function of $x$ in the end.

Now if you want to average the above result over $x$, to obtain $\int g(x)dx$, you are averaging the measures $F(x,dy)$ on $Y$ space with respect to $x$ to obtain (say) the measure $f(dy)$ on $Y$ space given by $f(dy)=\int F(x,dy)dx$, which acts on functions of $y$ by $h\mapsto \int_Y h(y) f(dy) = \int_Y h(y) \int_X F(x,dy) dx,$ and so on.

After having seen your edit 2 it is clear the measure is $\pi^*$ and $\pi$ is its density, so $\pi^*(A) = \int_A \pi(x)dx$ and $\pi^*(dx)=\pi(x)dx$. I'd say the author is sloppy and inconsistent: in (3.3.7) $\mu$ is a function and in (3.5.1) a measure, and it is no wonder you are confused.  I wonder (but please don't actually tell me) what his $M$ is: an operator on function space or an operator on measures, or the one disguised as the other.  My advice is to check your understanding in the discrete case, where everything is sums, and don't sweat the details of this author's notation for the more general situation.

Comment: If I may ask a follow up. In the second paragraph you say that the notation $\mu(f)$ is also valid. I ask because the text says $$\pi(f)=\int f(x)\pi(x)dx$$. This seems weird to me. To my understanding of your answer, if we integrate $f$ with respect to the measure $\pi$, we should get
$$\pi(f)=\int f(x)d\pi(x)=\int f(x)\pi(dx)$$
Could you please explain? Thank you very much

Comment: Without seeing exactly what your text says, and the context in which it says it, I don't know.  Presumably at some point it has defined $\pi(x)$ as a density function, and is not too particular about the distinction between a measure and its density function, at least in the section you are reading.

Comment: I am having trouble understanding this. Which one is correct? I thought they were conflicting. If I read somewhere
$$\pi(dx)$$
how am I to understand this? As $d\pi(x)$ or as $\pi(x)dx$? Because $d\pi(x)$ seems to be $\pi(x_{i+1})-\pi(x_i)$, and not $\pi(x)dx$.
What about
$$\pi(f)?$$

Comment: Without knowing what your book says exactly, I can't tell if it is using its own notation correctly or not.   It was presumably written by a human being, so is likely to be muddled or unclear in spots.  I suspect the book's $\pi(x)dx$ is an error or a notational quirk or sloppiness on its part.  What is the book, anyway?

Comment: I just wanted to say thank you for bearing with me. I understand everything now, after your edit :)